# gSOAP: How to send encrypted SOAP header

Tags: wcf, soap, web-services, gsoap, soapheader

I want to send some info, like user credentials in the SOAP header from my gSOAP client to my WCF webservice. I wish I could send them in encrypted form. I am using GPRS to commuicate. As GPRS bandwidth is low, I don't want to use HTTPS. So I want to encrypt the header only. Is it possible? If yes, how? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2006/04/23/141.aspx

or

maybe use http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/